# db2 create index but hit SQLSTATE=42703

Tags: unix, indexing, db2

I have a table created successfully.

1 of the column name is `code` and another 1 is "deleted".

Thus, I plan to use this 2 field to create its index. I am doing something like follow:

```
CREATE INDEX SADM.IDX_SC_IDX1 on SADM.SC ("code" ASC, "DELETED") ALLOW REVERSE SCANS;
```

This is working fine in my local. However, I hit this error in UAT:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0205N  Column, attribute, or period "code" is not defined in
"SADM.SC".  SQLSTATE=42703
```

I double check the table and confirm the "code" column or "deleted" is exist and same with my local.

I believe something wrong is inside but I cant find the root cause.

Kindly advise.

Comment: hi @mao, actually the table has schema, I already edit my question.

Comment: Edit the question to give Db2 server platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows) and Db2-version/fixpack details. Before the `create index` verify the uppercase/lowercase  of the target table columns, as you are using double-quotes they must match on case.

Comment: Hi @mao, I found the root cause base on your comment. You can put it as answer, and I will vote it as correct answer. its upppercase/lowercase issue. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment. You are using double-quotes around the column names the column case (uppercase, lowercase) must match between the table-definition and the index definition.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to name the columns as they were created and are listed in the system catalog. Look for the column names in `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` (for most Db2 versions). If you don't use quotes, Db2 converts identifiers to uppercase by default. However, if you use quotes they always need to be referenced exactly as written.

"code" is different from "Code" or "COde" or CODE. Thus, check how the column is really named.